# Footer is not sticking at the bottom

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer

No matter what I try (tutorials / posts on stackoverflow, w/e) I can't make my footer to stay at the bottom of my website.

I've created this custom theme for Wordpress (I didn't post it on wordpress stackexchange, because this is rather a CSS question than a WP question). Anyways, this is my website:
http://plexus-orthopedie.nl/wordpress/?page_id=1941

I did not put any content in my footer or any CSS so if anyone wants to try CSS code, it's easily possible.

The footer is located in:

```
html > body > div#page > footer.site-footer
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're asking for as there is no content in the footer to begin with. What do you mean by 'stay at the bottom'. what's happening to the footer when you add content?

Comment: you probably forgot to create footer.php file and connect <?php wp_footer(); ?>  to index.php

Comment: @AndrewMatthew As I wrote in my original post: I did not put any content in my footer or any CSS so if anyone wants to try CSS code, it's easily possible. Look at the HTML code, the footer is there.

Comment: @AlexPrinceton footer.php exists and wp_footer() is placed in my index.php file. This is not a problem where my footer is not showing. I want my footer to stick at the bottom. The current footer has no content, that's why it isn't visible. I only need CSS code to make it stick to the bottom

Comment: declare the footer after the closing main tag. - tried it in chrome inspect element and the footer stayed at the bottom

Comment: @AndrewMatthew which code did you use?

Comment: I took the everything in between and including the footer tags, cut that out of the main tags, and placed it outside of the main closing tag

Comment: @AndrewMatthew it's not working here. Can you post the exact code in a JSFiddle on how you fixed it? Thank you

Comment: @AngeloA http://jsfiddle.net/tqWhW/ I've coloured in the footer just so you can visually see it.

Comment: @AndrewMatthew Ah I see what you did. Only problem now: the footer's width is 100% but not the 100% of the viewport I want it to be. It can only be as wide as its parent.

Comment: The way that everything has been laid out is a bit harder for me to just cut in inspect element, but really you want the header, the main content, and the footer in separate divs without any parents. this way you can have the header width 100% like it does, the body be 960 or whatever it is with margin auto both left and right and then the footer width 100%. hopefully you catch my drift with that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe add something like this to your css style.

```
#page .site-footer {
    background-color: #123456;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I added a background-color to make it visible for now.

**EDIT:**

If you want the footer only to show on the bottom, not scrolling with you , add this instead of the above:

```
#page .site-footer {
    background-color: #123456;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 100%;
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**
I found the problem!

You have to change your div#content style.

Instead of

```
div#content{
    position: absolute;
}
```

use this:

```
 div#content{
     position: relative;
 }
```

And change your style for #page .site-footer to this:

```
#page .site-footer {
    background-color: #123456;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The problem was caused by the position:absolute in #content.

Comment: I don't want it to show all the time. I only want it to be at the bottom when the page is scrolled down.

Comment: give me a second, i had this before , let me change it

Comment: This is almost what I need! Only: margin-top:100% makes the page longer than it is (for example my homepage and contact page, producten page looks how it should). You know what causes this problem?

Comment: i understand what you mean, but for some reason i can't get it to work, have been looking at it for 20 minutes now. i will keep on trying, but have to say: it's weird that for some reason the footer is sticking above all the other content

Comment: It is weird, and I have no idea what causes the problem. All my width's and height's have been declared so it should be logical that my footer should stay at the bottom.

Comment: Finally a solution :-) Thank you Sten!

Answer (score 2):

use one that trick:

1. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/
2. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer

OR

**css**

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Sticky Footer Template for Bootstrap</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Begin page content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Sticky footer</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: All three ways are not working for my website. Footer gets placed somewhere in the middle of my page. I did try those methods already, tried them again but no result unfortunately :(

Comment: *EDIT* To be more specific on what's happening: the footer gets placed at the bottom of my viewport, but my page is scrollable, which causes the footer to be placed in the middle of my page.

Answer (score 2):

OK, after looking at your problem in a little more detail (im at work) i've found that you need to remove/add the following.

remove div id="page"

remove div id="content"

add the following css to div id="primary"

```
max-width: 980px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

add stuff to your footer, you'll see it's now working.

EDIT: css to header tag

```
top: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
.site-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

to see your footer you need content of course... or add a fixed width and height and a background-color

Comment: I want my footer to be at the bottom when my page is scrolled down. Not to show it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this issue, or at least one similar, myself.
I found that I had an extra closing div tag inside of my .wpwrap

.wpfooter should be inside of .wpwrap in order to stick to it's bottom (using pos: absolute & bottom 0 method)

The extra closing tag caused .wpwrap and .wpfooter to be siblings, so .wpfooter was positioned absolutely to body.

It's worth just checking the html structure to see where .wpfooter is being rendered.

I hope that makes sense and hopefully helps somebody! :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why but this works for me:

```
    #page .site-footer {

    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a quick way around it use this

in your css add `#footer { top: 100vh; position:relative; width: 100%;}`

in your html add `<div id="footer"><p>Hey look I was forced to be at the bottom</p></div>`

I hope this helps but keep in mind that while designing a page the only thing that should never be set statically is the height!

the best way to do it is by setting a min-height at the div content or if you feel lazy at the container or even to the body tag! usually I do this to the body tag `min-height: 100vh` and this will keep the footer always at the bottom without having to worry about future pages!

happy coding